# 3-letter "fontcode" for Cochineal font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, typography

On the Overleaf page https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces, a list of fonts and their 3-letter "fontcodes" are presented. However, not every font has been listed there. It is given that the 3-letter fontcode for the Latin Modern Roman font, for example, is `lmr`.

I am searching for the 3-letter fontcode for the Cochineal font and was wondering if anyone has a solution. The font in question can be gotten using the following command:

```
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}
\usepackage[scale=.95,type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[cochineal,bigdelims,cmintegrals,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[zerostyle=c,scaled=.94]{newtxtt}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
```

To summarize, I am searching for the 3-letter fontcode for the Cochineal font. Thanks.

Comment: it does not  use 3 letter names

Comment: Thank you for the information. Have you any idea about how I might be able to use it, say, for only a particular paragraph in a document that is in a different font?

Comment: look in the fd files eg `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Cochineal-OsF}{b}{n}` means `\fontfamily{Cochineal-OsF}\bfseries` would work

Comment: Thank you. How do I access the command you gave? Thanks once again.

Comment: access? you just type it. after loading the package or after `\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{Cochineal-OsF}{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}
\begin{document}

\showthe\font

\end{document}
```

shows

```
> \T1/Cochineal-OsF/m/n/10 .
<recently read> \font 
                      
l.6 \showthe\font
                 
?
```

so the family name is `Cochineal-OsF` and corresponds to the `fd` file `T1Cochineal-OsF.fd`  The original font family names were only 3-letter so that font files could get name, weight and size information in a 8+3 MSDOS / ISO-CD filesystem file name.

So to use this font just for a paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter\input{T1Cochineal-OsF.fd}\makeatother

\begin{document}

aaaaa [this is \expandafter\meaning\the\font]

{\fontfamily{Cochineal-OsF}\selectfont
 aaaaa [this is \expandafter\meaning\the\font]

}


aaaaa [this is \expandafter\meaning\the\font]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Fonts used to have three-letter family names to keep all the filenames short enough for MS-DOS.  Now that that is no longer necessary, font families have longer names.

Today, practically all fonts (except for a few retro throwbacks such as `cmathbb`) are created in a modern, portable format, which `fontspec` also understands.  Then, if legally permitted, someone runs the file through a converter and exports a package compatible with PDFTeX, which then goes up on CTAN.  The family names created this way are usually Fontname-LF (for lining figures), plus a few others such as Fontname-OsF (for old-style figures, with inexplicable capitalization).

If the command `\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{familyname}\selectfont` works, there’s a file somewhere in your TeX tree named `t1familyname.fd`.  So you can searcch your TeX directory (or just its `texmf-dist` subdirectory, if it was installed by an official package) for files named `*Familyname*.fd`.  (This should be case-insensitive.)

Alternatively, [the package listings on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/cochineal) link to [a directory of all files shipped with the package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cochineal), so you can browse that and see what `.fd` files it has.  They’re typically in a subdirectory named `tex`.

In this case, we see that the family name you want to use is either `Cochineal-LF` or `Cochineal-OsF` (for lining or old-style figures, repectively), and that there are also a `mincochineal` family, a `zcochmi` math alphabet (with no upright lowercase Greek letters), and some variants for things like tabular figures and denominators that you would not normally use as a body font.

Comment: Thank you for the response.